# Ruby, Prefer {...} over do...end for single-line blocks. But error

Tags: ruby, lint, rubocop

I have this code in a .rb Class file:

`field :user, Types::UserType do resolve ->(_obj, _args, ctx) { ctx[:user] } end`

what I need is to remove `do` and `end` from the single line using, I think, the `{}`.

`[Style/BlockDelimiters] Prefer`{...}`over`do...end`for single-line blocks.`

But I don't understand why it throws this error:

```
[ruby] syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting '('
[ruby] syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
```

### RuboCop version

```
$ rubocop -V
0.51.0 (using Parser 2.4.0.2, running on ruby 2.4.2 x64-mingw32)
```

Comment: “what I need is to remove”—you do not need to blindly follow everything that rubocop says in the first place. If you still want to satisfy it, manage the operator precedence properly, possibly with parentheses around `Types::UserType`.

Comment: @mudasobwa I think it would be around the whole of the argument list e.g. `field(:user, Types::UserType) do #etc` that being said it would read better as 2 lines or using the more natural inline block syntax.

Comment: `field(:user, Types::UserType) { resolve ->(_obj, _args, ctx) { ctx[:user] } }`

Comment: @engineersmnky, what is the `more natural inline block syntax`?

Comment: See @gabrielhilal comment. It is more natural (read idiomatic) to use curly braces `{...}` to denote an inline block. The internal parser does not disallow the use of `do...end` as an inline block it is just not generally considered proper style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To appease the Rubocop, switch either to this:

```
field :user, Types::UserType do
  resolve ->(_obj, _args, ctx) { ctx[:user] }
end
```

Or this:

```
field(:user, Types::UserType) { resolve ->(_obj, _args, ctx) { ctx[:user] } }
```

I'd argue the former is a lot cleaner than the latter, but it's up to you.

Comment: @engineersmnky I stand correct then. I wonder when they fixed that. Presumably 1.9.

Comment: @engineersmnky Same. Maybe I'm confusing this with some other quirk of the syntax. I've updated the answer.

Comment: The latter is invalid on 2.4.

Comment: This could be due to the ambiguity of the binding there, where it's not clear if that block is supplied to `Types::UserType` or to `field`. I've updated it with valid syntax.